# Rails Heroku hits memory quota too fast

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a Rails application hosted on heroku, the big problem is that I hit memory quota too fast, when I restart the dyno I got 280MB in web.1 and worker.1 180MB, and that's fine, but when requests comes the memory usage for to web.1 start to increase, if there is a timeout the memory increases again and a lot, and if 3 connections come at the same time, the application runs slow, and the memory goes to the sky, and then I need to restart the dyno again. I have web concurrency configured to 1 and I serve the JS application from cloudfront and some images too. The server only handles CSS and normal requests. I have a Hobby dyno, I don't know how to scale the app, or avoid the memory quota every half hour. Forgive me for my english, and thank you.

Comment: The scope of this question is too broad. Try monitoring the logs and see where the code breaks (exceptions usually cause memory leaks, if not handled properly).

Comment: Using a tool such as NewRelic will also help to figure out what part(s) of your application is (are) burning your memory. Once identified, just refactor your app to limit its memory consumption